# Cmake/Mingw32: cmake command fails - testCCompiler.c not found

Tags: c++, cmake, cygwin, mingw32

I have a problem while running cmake with a mingw32 custom compiler in a cygwin terminal.
I have already tried several approaches to fix my problem, until I got to the point where it only fails on finding `testCCompiler.c` from the directory `CmakeTmp`.

When I try to manually `make` the temporary files after cmake failed, the make command runs successfully. (Used `--debug-trycompile` to keep temporary files)

This is the output from the `CMakeError.log` file:

```
Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_5e0c4/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e0c4.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e0c4.dir/build
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp“ wird betreten
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e0c4.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
/opt/mingw32-1.6.0/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-6.1.0.exe     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e0c4.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-6.1.0.exe: error: /cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c: No such file or directory
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-6.1.0.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e0c4.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e0c4.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Fehler 1
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp“ wird verlassen
make: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_5e0c4/fast] Fehler 2
```

As I see it, the file `testCCompiler.c` is missing while running `gcc-6.1.0`.
But when I compile it manually after cmake has failed, it runs successfully. When I run `make` in the specific directory it works as well (BUT: compiler identification is **6.4.0** while my custom compiler id is **6.1.0**).

Running `mingw32-make` manually for `testCCompiler.c`:

```
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -H/cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp -B/cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_start /cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles /cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
C:/Cygwin/opt/mingw32-1.6.0/bin/mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
C:/Cygwin/opt/mingw32-1.6.0/bin/mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_033c1.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_033c1.dir/depend
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'D:/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
cd /cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp && /usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp /cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp /cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp /cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp /cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTC_033c1.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target cmTC_033c1
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
C:/Cygwin/opt/mingw32-1.6.0/bin/mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_033c1.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_033c1.dir/build
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'D:/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_033c1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
/usr/bin/cc     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_033c1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
[100%] Linking C executable cmTC_033c1.exe
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_033c1.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc     -Wl,--enable-auto-import  CMakeFiles/cmTC_033c1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_033c1.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_033c1.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
[100%] Built target cmTC_033c1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_start /cygdrive/d/programming/cpp/T2D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 0
```

My top level `CMakeLists.txt` is just a simple one, for testing my toolchain configuration:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(T2D)
add_executable(T2D main.cpp)
```

The `cmake` command is in a seperate bash file and looks like this:

```
cmake .. --debug-trycompile -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-6.1.0 \
         -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=i686-w64-mingw32-g++ \
         -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/mingw32-1.6.0/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.1.0 /opt/mingw32-1.6.0/i686-w64-mingw32/lib" \
         -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH="/opt/mingw32-1.6.0/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/include /opt/mingw32-1.6.0/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/include-fixed /opt/mingw32-1.6.0/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/include/c++ /opt/mingw32-1.6.0/i686-w64-mingw32/include/"
```

Does anyone see what's going wrong, besides the wrong compiler identification? (How does that happen anyway? I've already tried setting the `CC` and `CXX` vars too, but that still doesnt change anything; `make` and `mingw32-make` still always use **6.4.0** instead of **6.1.0**)

Comment: `But when I compile it manually after cmake has failed, it runs successfully.` - Because CMake uses system compiler in that case, `/usr/bin/cc`. Instead of running `make`, execute command which shows CMake: `/opt/mingw32-1.6.0/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-6.1.0.exe     -o ...`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Actually I have worked out the problem. I backed up the system cmake package and installed a custom one and used the `MinGW Makefiles` generator. Now it was using the correct compiler. So for this simple program, it works at the moment.